# Some text area persistently highlighted in Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

When I use eclipse if neon to type javascript file ,I often come to white color which covers the words I typing as this pictures:
[image]

I have to close this file and open again, it will be disappear, but it will appear soon.

How should I solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some hover for a previous Search request. Open the `Search` view, and clear the active search to remove highlights.